# Opening solution in VS 2017 Preview removed binding to VSTS repository

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, tfvc

I have a WebJobs project that I've been working on in Visual Studio 2017 for some time. The solution is also checked into a repository on VSTS.

I also have Visual Studio 2017 Preview version installed on my computer and I mistakenly opened my WebJobs projects in this version.

First, I noticed that my solution was no longer bound to the repository and I could not check my code in.

I then opened the solution in stable version of Visual Studio 2017 and click "Add solution to source control". When I look at the binding, it seems to be pointing to the right repository but under "Pending Changes", I don't see all the changes I've made to the project.

Is there a clean fix to this? Otherwise, I'll kill the repository on VSTS, create a new one and do a clean check-in. I'd hate to go through that process though if I can fix the problem.

UPDATE:
When I click "Workspaces", I see my computer's name and "Workspaces..." options and if I select "Workspaces...", I can see all them on my computer. In the "Edit" view, they even seem mapped correctly. But as you can see in the image below, it shows the "Local Path: Not Mapped".
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you double check if it's the same workspace or different when you use VS 2017 preview version and VS 2017 stable version?

Comment: Yikes!!! Looks like all my mappings got removed! Even when I opened the solution that I created using the Preview version of VS 2017, I noticed that my solution is no longer mapped to my repository. What do I do? In these situations, I'm scared silly that I'll mess up the code in the repository. I now have an older version of the code in the repository and my solutions with updates on my local machine but it's not mapped to the repository.

Comment: Not sure what actions you took. But can you select other workspaces from the dropdown list (https://imgur.com/a/HyGRq)? If you can not find the mapped workspace, you can add a new workspace and map again, then copy the changes files and checkin changes.

Comment: Just posted what I'm seeing as an update to the original post. As you can see, the workspaces are there and they even seem mapped correctly in the "Edit" view but in "Source Control Explorer", it clearly shows "Not mapped". This is also evident from the fact that I can't check my code in. This all happened when I opened my solution in Visual Studio 2017 15.6.1 Preview 1. Not sure how to proceed and fix this issue and would appreciate pointers. Thanks!

Comment: Can you display the source control folder for workspace MOUNTAINEER_2? And what's your TFVC repo name you are working with (like `$/project`)? Did you map the TFVC repo (like `$/project`) in your workspace?